# Getting the integer solution for inequalities(positive solutions x,y,z)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equations:

x = l

y = 5n - 2l + 25

z = 10 - 2n

I need to get how many integer solution we have positive (x,y,z). So I proceeded as follows

l > 0

5n - 2l + 25 > 0 AND 10 - 2n > 0

we get the following inequality -5 + 2l/5 < n < 5 
-25 < n - 2l < 25 However I want to get how many integer solutions are there without resorting to brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: If $n \leq 0 \to n = 0,-1,-2,-3,-4$ because $0 < y =5n - 2l + 25 = 5n - 2x + 25 < 5n + 25 \to n > -5$, and you can check case by case. If $n > 0 \to z = 10 - 2n > 0 \to n < 5 \to n = 1, 2,3, 4$, and you can check each case.

Comment: how did you get for n <= 0 $\rightarrow$ n = 0,-1,-2,-3,-4?

Comment: I don't think we have -3,-4 because the way I see it is as follows we have n > -5 + 2l/5 and l > 0 so to get an integer we must have 5 | l so first l > 0 is l = 5 so we have n > -5 + 2 so we get n > -3 and n < 5 so we have (-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4) right?

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: so there is only I guess 9 solutions corresponding to l = 5 and l = 10 I think I will make a separate question about this to make sure.